# Запятая при "скорее всего"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, сложное-предложение

Пример следующий:

"Он полагал, что, вернись он в прошлое, скорее всего снова поступил бы так же".

Правильно ли расставлены запятые? И что самое главное: нужно ли здесь обособлять "скорее всего"? Это правило про то, что вводные слова не выделяются в начале обособленных оборотов (деепричастия, причастия, приложения и прочее), если честно, сильно путает. В примере сложное предложение. Нужно ставить запятую или нет? Если было бы "то", тогда бы обособлялось, но если без? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "То" без "если" нельзя.

Comment: Можно, можно, я  разрешаю)))  Все-то у вас нельзя.

Comment: Я тоже за. В "вернись" заложен весь смысл "если бы вернулся".

Comment: Из словаря Ушакова: "То" употребляется в начале главного предложения для большего выражения связи его с придаточным, **начинающимся с условного или причинного союза**, если это придаточное предшествует и, в особенности, если оно притом сильно распространено.

Comment: *Вернись он в прошлое, то, скорее всего, снова поступил бы так же.* Это нормальное предложение? Это гибридный вариант, не норма.

Comment: А как насчет синтаксического разбора "гибридного" варианта?

Comment: Может, грамматического? Наличие "то" на синтаксис и грамматику не влияет.

Comment: Синтаксис – это вроде бы часть грамматики

Comment: Да, но в синтаксис не входит строение предложения (ССП, СПП и т.п.).

Comment: Ага, не входит! Вот моя настольная книга: Синтаксис современного русского языка.  Оттуда в я все и списываю))

Comment: Но обычно синтаксический разбор — это про члены предложения, а грамматический — это про строение.

Comment: Прочитайте оглавление   https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Пусть будет так. Тогда в чём разница между грамматическим и синтаксическим разбором?

Comment: Если это то же самое, то только один вариант должен быть правильным.

Answer (score 2):

Правило довольно простое.

Если «скорее всего» употребляется в значении «вероятнее всего», то:

Ставятся 2 запятые (с двух сторон), когда это вводное слово, например: «Завтра, скорее всего, мы ничего не успеем.»

Ставится 1 запятая (перед «скорее всего»), когда оно стоит перед причастным/деепричастным оборотом. Например: «Мы бежали по эскалатору, скорее всего уже опаздывая на электричку.»

Но если «скорее всего» употребляется в значении «быстрее всего», то запятые не нужны: «Тут можно проехать скорее всего и без пробок.»

В твоем случае это вводное слово, после которого нет причастного/деепричастного оборота, поэтому запятые должны ставиться с двух сторон от «скорее всего»: «Он полагал, что, вернись он в прошлое, скорее всего, снова поступил бы так же». Надеюсь помог! :)

Comment: Знать правила — это прекрасно, как без них!  А про грамматику предложения ничего не скажете? Она довольно интересная. И еще вопрос от автора.  Если использовать "то", изменится пунктуация?

Answer (score 2):

**Два варианта записи:**

*(1) Он полагал, что, вернись он в прошлое, ***скорее всего***, снова поступил бы так же.*

*(2) Он полагал, что вернись он в прошлое, **то,** ***скорее всего,*** снова поступил бы так же.*

Здесь три грамматические основы.

**Последовательное** подчинение: придаточное изъяснительное и придаточное условное.

Придаточное условное содержит **логическое обоснование** (предположение и умозаключение). Смысл такой: если бы он вернулся в прошлое, то поступил так же.  Условного союза нет, замена сослагательного наклонения (если бы вернулся) формой повелительного наклонения (вернись).

Если используется указательное местоимение ТО, тогда запятая после ЧТО не ставится.

***Скорее всего*** – это вводное слово, но здесь у него **особая роль**. Оно участвует в двуместном союзном образовании: если бы... скорее всего. Сравнить: **Раз** вы читаете это мое письмецо, **значит**, я вас уже покинул... (Из Справочника по пунктуации).

Comment: Sharon, всё очень хорошо! Только о запятой после "скорее всего" не сказали.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!  Про самое главное забыла написать. Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Дело не в возможности замены. Дело в том, что такое не употребляется. Если бы всё, чем можно заменить, можно было бы использовать... (Например, если синоним, то значит, что всегда можно заменить.) "То" — это вторая часть союза, нигде нет того, что оно может быть самостоятельным союзом. Не хватает ссылки, где бы это разрешалось. Но не будет, потому что это не звучит.

Comment: Это обычный двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, вы его не узнали, что ли.  Просто первой части нет (вместо сослагательного наклонения используется повелительное).

Comment: Не может быть такого, что первой части нет. Если первая часть опущена, то её можно вставить (без изменения предложения). Не хитрите.

Comment: А вы вырешили меня перехитрить, да? Зовите своих присяжных, пусть решают, кто прав.

Comment: Нет, у меня всё честно)

Comment: Ну давайте я вам придумаю предложение.  "Выйди мы хотя бы на 5 минут раньше, то, скорее  всего, успели бы на поезд".

Comment: Порой оно лучше звучит. Оно должно всегда хорошо звучать, чтобы быть правильным. Разговорный (читерский) вариант.

Comment: Лучше не получилось, это разговорная речь. Но в заданном вопросе грамматика точно такая же. Так что сдавайте уж свои позиции.

Comment: Не, чуть удачнее, может, это из-за длины придаточного. Разговорная речь может быть правильной, а может быть читерской.

Comment: *Так что сдавайте уж свои позиции* — вам для этого надо источник найти, где бы говорилось, что "то" может существовать само по себе. Но это не используется и противоречит грамматике.

Comment: Ладно, вас сегодня не убедишь. Как нибудь при случае.  И вообще я целый день в чем-то вас убеждаю и что-то доказываю. А где ваша активная позиция? Вы мне даже своего грамматического разбора не представили, только меня критикуете. Даже поздороваться забыли, как-то это невежливо.

Comment: Изначально вы отреагировали на мой комментарий, а не наоборот) *вас сегодня не убедишь* — потому что не спорю, когда не прав (непосредственно синтаксис не в счёт, им не занимаюсь).